# Quantity based discount for single product in Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, how-to

I'm using latest build of Expresso Store, 2.3.1. I need to apply quantity based discounts to products, but the discount needs to apply to a single product. For example:

I have 10% off discount for all products in store when you order 10 or more of a single product, but the discount only applies to the particular product. So I order 11 of Product 1, 10 of Product 2 and 5 of Product 3. Products 1 and 2 will get the discount, product 3 will be full price.

As far as I can see this is not possible in Store. If so are there any ways I can handle this in the template? As our discount will likely be pretty simple, with the same discount being applied store wide.

Failing that, what are our options for extending Store to achieve this?

Update: Just to clarify, we are looking to apply this discount at a category or store wide level, rather than updating the pricing of an individual product, as there are thousands of products this would not be viable, in particular as we will likely just have one percentage discount that is the same for all products.

Answer (score 1):

Use this [bulk discounts add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/store-bulk-discount), does exactly what you need. Create a new field type and discounts are controlled per product and at definable quantities.

Does need Matrix installed though.

Comment: Thanks Peter. That's not going to work for us though, as I understand it that's applied at the product level. So I would need to update each of the thousands of products to update the discount. As the discount is applied most likely at the same rate across all products, we really need to be applying the discount once either via a promotion, plugin of some sort or in the template. Documentation is also MIA, but I excluded it before because it appears to not do percentage discounts either.

Comment: You will probably have to extend store via an extension and utilise its hooks.

Answer (score 0):

We've just had the bulk discount configured to work with store 2.4 by another extension developer. 
You're right, it doesn't accept percentage discounts however you could easily use [Datagrab](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab) to import the matrix fields all at once across any product range you wanted.

I'm sure we could put you in touch with the developer that made the add on compatible with store 2 if you wanted...